# how to implement movable overloads without violating the DRY principle in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

While implementing method and operator overloading in some of my classes to leverage the rvalue references in C++, often I write some code with poor design violating the DRY Principle. What would be a better alternative for the code snippet below? (This code is just to illustrate the problem)

```
class matrix_2_2
{
    int _m[2][2];

public:

    matrix_2_2 operator*(const matrix_2_2& m) const &
    {   
        matrix_2_2 res;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
                for(int k = 0 ; k < 2 ; k++)
                    res._m[i][j] = (res._m[i][j] + _m[i][k]*m._m[k][j]);

        return res;
    }

    matrix_2_2 operator*(matrix_2_2&& m) &&
    {
        matrix_2_2 res;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
                for(int k = 0 ; k < 2 ; k++)
                    res._m[i][j] = (res._m[i][j] + _m[i][k]*m._m[k][j]);

        return move(res);
    }
```

This code presents a lot of repetition in the implementations details, I would like to encapsulate the logic and reuse it in different overloads, without losing the movable advantage because of rvalue to lvalue implicity conversions.

Comment: You may define a third function and have the two `operator*` call into it.

Comment: @Lingxi, in this situation I'd pass `const matrix_2_2&` or `matrix_2_2&&`? I thought about this alternative but could not reach any conclusion about the types being passed do the function.

Comment: You don't need the overloading for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better alternative would be to just delete the rvalue-qualified `operator*` completely and have just the one `operator*`, this one:

```
    matrix_2_2 operator*(const matrix_2_2& m) const;
```

Your class is a POD - there is no difference between a move and a copy in this case, so there is no possible advantage for you to gain by taking advantage of move semantics. You're gaining in code complexity, but not in performance. There really is no logical difference for what your code should do if `this` is `&` or `&&`...

Also, this:

```
matrix_2_2 operator*(matrix_2_2&& m) &&
{
    matrix_2_2 res;
    ...
    return std::move(res);
}
```

is not the correct way to write that, as the last `move` makes it impossible to do the named return value optimization, so you're doing an extra `move` for code like:

```
matrix_2_2 product = some_matrix() * some_other_matrix();
```

Rather than simply constructing `res` in-place in `product`.

Comment: Ok, in this example the class is a POD, but in a more complex scenario it would not be, I would like to know a better design for reusing the core  implementations details in different overloads, while also leveraging the rvalue optimization.

Comment: About the `return std::move(res);` I didn't know that it would hurt the return value optimization, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @LunaticSoul If you have a more complex scenario in which move semantics apply, I'd just ask a question about that scenario. Definitely if you find yourself writing *identical* code, you can easily just delete the duplicate.

Comment: @Barry agreed. The matrix example is quite particular.

Comment: @Barry, if the matrix_2_2 had, say, different constructors overloads would it make any difference? Perhaps, I have not make it clear, but what I really would like to know is whether or not is possible to implement rvalue references overloads without code repetition, because in all the examples that I have seen, this kind of DRY principle violation always occurs.

Comment: This matrix_2_2 was just to illustrate, if you have some scenario where some movable overload was implemented without code duplication it'd be great.  I just can't think to properly use it without some code smell.

Comment: I'm upvoting since this is the only sane conclusion, but it has nothing to do with POD-ness. The overload simply doesn't contribute anything but complexity.

Comment: Aside from what's been pointed out about move semantics not aiding cases where there is no notion of a cheap shallow copy (ex: no pointers in the class to an external buffer), there are some legitimate cases where you might be concerned with the DRY principle. There you want to prioritize eliminating the duplication of non-trivial logic more than anything else, since that's where you're at the highest risk of duplicating bugs and increasing maintenance cost, risk of asymmetrical changes leading to bugs and so forth....

Comment: ... so, for example, one way to eliminate such duplication of non-trivial logic in legit cases is to implement `operator*` in terms of `operator*=`.